# Call C# dll from VB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll

I am using a C# DLL from an VB project, so far I hadn't problems, but after updating DLL version I have some compilation errors when calling functions, I'm not sure if the problem comes from optional parameters or output parameters.

In short, my problem is the opposite to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713818/using-a-vb-net-dll-in-c-getting-invalid-argument).

This is an example of function definition in DLL (if I fix this one it happens in other function calls, it's a BIG dll):

```
public static bool RequestCode(string countryCode, string phoneNumber, out string password, string method = "sms", string id = null, string language = null, string locale = null, string mcc = "204", string salt = "")
public static bool RequestCode(string countryCode, string phoneNumber, out string password, out string response, string method = "sms", string id = null, string language = null, string locale = null, string mcc = "204", string salt = "")
public static bool RequestCode(string countryCode, string phoneNumber, out string password, out string request, out string response, string method = "sms", string id = null, string language = null, string locale = null, string mcc = "204", string salt = "")
```

This is my call from VB (all of them throw error):

```
result = ThatLibrary.ThatClass.RequestCode(country, telephone, pass, cc, method)
```

Or

```
result = ThatLibrary.ThatClass.RequestCode(country, telephone, pass, method)
```

Or

```
result = ThatLibrary.ThatClass.RequestCode(country, telephone, pass, method, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "204", "")
```

Or

```
result = ThatLibrary.ThatClass.RequestCode(countryCode:=pais, phoneNumber:=telefono, password:=password, method:=metodo, id:=Nothing, language:=Nothing, locale:=Nothing, mcc:="204", salt:="")
```

And this is error message:

> Error 3   'RequestCode' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class 'ThatClass'.

After some days looking for a soluction I'm considering moving all my project to C# but this is a huge task so I hope there's a simple solution I missed...

Comment: Don't do that.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/10/optional-arguments-on-both-ends.aspx

Comment: I don't know, but C# has a way to specify named optional parameters. If vb.net has that, that could fix your problem. But really, you need to clean up those signatures.

Comment: It does.  Send hate-mail to that C# programmer.

Comment: @SLaks, it's not my DLL, Hans Passant good idea, he is nice enough to give me that DLL for free though ;-). crashmstr will try that

Comment: @crashmstr, added named parameters and get same error, it was a good idea anyway

Comment: In C# there is no problem identifying the correct method call since the 'out'/'ref' keywords in the call give more information to the compiler.  Unfortunately, VB doesn't use similar keywords in method calls, so you haven't got as much freedom in VB for the compiler to pick the appropriate overload.

Comment: Your last VB call - naming all parameters - *does* work.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas nop, I get same error

Comment: @K.Weber: I think it's probably because I tested from VB with the methods defined in VB, not C#.

Comment: @K.Weber: I just tested with the methods defined in a C# project and calling from VB, and the last VB call (naming all parameters) does indeed work.  You should try that again and let us know the exact error you get on that last call.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: `Error 3 'RequestCode' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class 'ThatClass'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name all your parameters for this case to work in VB.
Your last method call (naming all parameters) works with the following test:

C# dll:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    class ThatClass
    {
        public static string RequestCode(string countryCode, string phoneNumber, out string password, string method = "sms", string id = null, string language = null, string locale = null, string mcc = "204", string salt = "") { password = ""; return ""; }
        public static string RequestCode(string countryCode, string phoneNumber, out string password, out string response, string method = "sms", string id = null, string language = null, string locale = null, string mcc = "204", string salt = "") { password = "";  response = ""; return ""; }
        public static string RequestCode(string countryCode, string phoneNumber, out string password, out string request, out string response, string method = "sms", string id = null, string language = null, string locale = null, string mcc = "204", string salt = "") { password = ""; response = ""; request = ""; return ""; }
    }
}
```

VB project, referencing the C# dll:

```
Class ThisClass
    Sub testing()
        Dim country As String = "USA"
        Dim telephone As String = "555-555-5555"
        Dim pass As String = ""
        Dim cc As String = ""
        Dim method As String = ""
        Dim test As String = ClassLibrary1.ThatClass.RequestCode(countryCode:=country, phoneNumber:=telephone, password:=pass, method:=method, id:=Nothing, language:=Nothing, locale:=Nothing, mcc:="204", salt:="")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I agree this _should_ work, so I must be missing something else, I'll give it another try

Comment: The problem seemed to be in Visual Studio version, project making use of DLL was in Visual Studio 2008 (:-S yes!) and I went to VS2012 and it's working now