# VB.NET "System.EntryPointNotFoundException" for function in a DLL but dumpbin /EXPORTS shows no names

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to get my VB.NET 2017 windows forms GUI to call a function in a DLL (InhecoMTCDLL.dll) that is provided by the company Inheco.com .
Inheco says DLL works with a C# app ok, but example C# program is not available, and source of there DLL is not available.  They say they only support C# and not VB.
My app is in VB.NET and is already written.

VB & DLL PROPERTIES

```
dotPeek reports that DLL is:
x86  .NET Framework 3.5

My VB.NET app is:

    Target CPU is:  x86
    .NET Framework 4.5.1   (build fails for 3.5)
```

VB.NET DECLARATION  ----------  My VB.NET declaration is this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Thermoshake_Interface
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' DLL INTERFACE DECLARATIONS...

    ' Function within DLL:  
    ' Public int FindTheUniversalControl(int ID);
    ' which corresponds to VB.NET declaration:                
    <DllImport("InhecoMTCdll.dll")>
    Public  Function FindTheUniversalControl(byval ID As Int32) As Int32
    End Function



End Module
```

VB CALL TO DLL  -----------  And, my app's call to the function in the DLL is this:

```
Private Sub Button_test_Thermoshake_DLL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_test_Thermoshake_DLL.Click
    Stop ' and test!!!

    Dim Thermoshake_controller_ID_int32 as int32 = 0       
    Dim return_status As Int32
    return_status = Thermoshake_Interface.FindTheUniversalControl( Thermoshake_controller_ID_int32 )
    TextBox_Thermoshake_communication.Text &= "FindTheUniversalControl(0) returned " & return_status
```

End Sub

E R R O R   ------------  The error that I get is:

```
"Unable to find an entry point named 'FindTheUniversalControl' in DLL 'InhecoMTCdll.dll'.":""}  System.EntryPointNotFoundException
```

D U M P B I N   -----------  The dumpbin output below shows no exported functions.  The DLL source code is not available.  However, dotPeek decompiles it and I see the 'FindTheUniversalControl' there, but I'm not a dotPeek export:

```
C:\PRIMARY\MUSE_BIO\WORK\SYSTEM GUI V1>dumpbin inhecomtcdll.dll /exports
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.10.25019.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file inhecomtcdll.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        6000 .text
```

D o t P e e k   ------   dotPeek decompilation of function and its class:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: InhecoMTCdll.GlobCom
// Assembly: InhecoMTCdll, Version=1.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 054E16B0-4E1E-48C4-B9BF-9443EECE4E3D
// Assembly location: C:\PRIMARY\me\WORK\Thermoshake DLL project\InhecoMTCdll.dll

using HID_Test_Application;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

namespace InhecoMTCdll
{
  [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof (InhecoMTCEvents))]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  [Guid("0CEE0396-3016-41db-B914-0C94132DEA8B")]
  public class GlobCom : InhecoMTCInterface
  {
    private Hid _TTHID = new Hid();
    private DeviceManagement _MyDeviceManagement = new DeviceManagement();
    public System.Timers.Timer timerTimeout = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private WaitHandle[] waithandleTT = new WaitHandle[3];
    private IntPtr _DeviceNotificationHandle;
    public int _HIDHandle;
    public int _ReadHandle;
    public int _WriteHandle;
    private bool _MyDeviceDetected;
    private string _MyDevicePathName;
    private string wholeReply;
    private bool griechished;
    private byte finish;
    private int localDeviceID;
    public string puStrResult;
    private byte crc;
    private bool bResend;
    private string localMSG;

...
    public int FindTheUniversalControl(int ID)
    {
      Guid empty = Guid.Empty;
      HidApiDeclarations.HidD_GetHidGuid(ref empty);
      empty.ToString();
      string[] devicePathName = new string[128];
      int numberOfInputBuffers = 32;
      int num1 = 1003;
      int num2 = 8227 + ID;
      int num3 = 0;
      int num4 = 0;
      this.localDeviceID = ID;
      FileIOApiDeclarations.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes = new FileIOApiDeclarations.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
      this.timerTimeout.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timerTimeout_Tick);
      if (this._MyDeviceManagement.FindDeviceFromGuid(empty, ref devicePathName))
      {
        this.timerTimeout.Interval = 500.0;
        int index = 0;
        do
        {
          this._HIDHandle = FileIOApiDeclarations.CreateFile(devicePathName[index], 0U, 3U, ref lpSecurityAttributes, 3, 0U, 0);
          if (this._HIDHandle != -1)
          {
            this._TTHID.DeviceAttributes.Size = Marshal.SizeOf((object) this._TTHID.DeviceAttributes);
            if (HidApiDeclarations.HidD_GetAttributes(this._HIDHandle, ref this._TTHID.DeviceAttributes) != 0)
            {
              if ((int) this._TTHID.DeviceAttributes.VendorID == num1 & (int) this._TTHID.DeviceAttributes.ProductID == num2)
              {
                this._MyDeviceDetected = true;
                this._MyDevicePathName = devicePathName[index];
                num4 = 1;
              }
              else
              {
                this._MyDeviceDetected = false;
                num3 = FileIOApiDeclarations.CloseHandle(this._HIDHandle);
                num4 = 0;
              }
            }
            else
            {
              this._MyDeviceDetected = false;
              num3 = FileIOApiDeclarations.CloseHandle(this._HIDHandle);
              num4 = 0;
            }
          }
          ++index;
        }
        while (!(this._MyDeviceDetected | index == devicePathName.Length));
      }
      if (this._MyDeviceDetected)
      {
        bool flag = this._MyDeviceManagement.RegisterForDeviceNotifications(this._MyDevicePathName, empty, ref this._DeviceNotificationHandle);
        this._TTHID.Capabilities = this._TTHID.GetDeviceCapabilities(this._HIDHandle);
        if (flag)
        {
          this._TTHID.GetHIDUsage(this._TTHID.Capabilities);
          this._TTHID.GetNumberOfInputBuffers(this._HIDHandle, ref numberOfInputBuffers);
          this._ReadHandle = FileIOApiDeclarations.CreateFile(this._MyDevicePathName, 2147483648U, 3U, ref lpSecurityAttributes, 3, 1073741824U, 0);
          if (this._ReadHandle != -1)
            this._WriteHandle = FileIOApiDeclarations.CreateFile(this._MyDevicePathName, 1073741824U, 3U, ref lpSecurityAttributes, 3, 0U, 0);
          this._TTHID.FlushQueue(this._ReadHandle);
        }
      }
      return num4;
    }
```

Comment: If you can see the signature in dotPeek does that not suggest the DLL is an assembly that can simply be referenced?

Comment: I added reference, and get the same error.

Comment: I do believe you'll find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482045/call-c-sharp-dll-from-vb

Comment: If it's a .NET DLL (which it looks like from the information you provided), you do not need to define it in your code (you can delete your `Thermoshake_Interface` module) - just add a reference and the appropriate `Imports` statement (or fully qualify the name).  However, since the method is `public int FindTheUniversalControl(int ID)`, which is an instance method (not static/Shared), you will need to call it through an instance of whatever class it is defined on.  You haven't provided enough information to determine what that class is.

Comment: I added the function and its class above.

Comment: I can see the DLL's GlobCom class in my app's object browser.  But don't know how to create instance of a DLL class.